# Problems with implode() function when I use global array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    $atributos = array("id","attr1","attr2","attr4");
    function dinamico()
    {
       $stringData = implode(",",$atributos);
       echo $stringData;
    } 
?>
```

and it give this:

> Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

if I declare this array inside function, It works but not out of it.

Note: I need to declare it outside because I use this array too times.

Comment: Your question title says global array, but you have not indicated it as global within your function.

Comment: nope you have to call a globals like $GLOBALS['atributos'] in the implode function..  see here for reference: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

Comment: @Plum yes, it was the problem, thanks.

Comment: why downvoted? sorry for my english!

Comment: Dunno, but your edit definitely deserves a downvote...

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using global, you can pass the array as an argument to your function.

```
<?php

function dinamico($atributos)  // add a parameter here
{
   $stringData = implode(",",$atributos);
   echo $stringData;
}

$atributos = array("id","attr1","attr2","attr4");  // declare the array outside the function

dinamico($atributos);  // pass the array to the function when you call it
```

An advantage to doing it this way rather than using `global $atributos;` inside your function (which would also work) is that it allows your function to be *self-contained* rather than forcing it to depend on the existence of a variable with a certain name outside its scope.